# How do I apply a condition to a grouped query in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way, using **T-SQL**, to group items in this table by ItemId, and select the first supported date value based on the bit value in the Supported column (or the **last** for the grouping, if none are marked as supported)

**Table**

```
ItemId  | Date      | Supported
===================================
1       | 1/1/2001  | 0
1       | 1/1/2002  | 1
1       | 1/1/2003  | 0
2       | 1/1/2001  | 0
2       | 1/1/2002  | 0
2       | 1/1/2003  | 0
```

**Pseudo Code**

```
SELECT MAX(Date WHERE Supported=1 (Or Last)) FROM Table GROUP BY ItemId
```

**Desired Results**

```
ItemId  | Date  
======================
1       | 1/1/2002  
2       | 1/1/2003
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `coalesce()` with `group by`:

```
select itemid,
       coalesce( min(case when supported = 1 then date end),
                 max(date)
               )
from t
group by itemid;
```